# Excel VBA Accumulator and InputBox Errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question. To keep the story short, I am trying to see the number of unique identifiers that exist in all five columns of a table of data (not just in one, two, three, or four of the columns). The data represents respondents that have completed a survey at different time periods. I have written VBA to count the number of unique identifiers that show up in all five columns, but something is going wrong when I try to use an inputbox to assign values to my variables, and something is going wrong with my accumulator. I get runtime error 104 when I use inputbox, and resorted to assigning values to my variables in the code itself (not good practice, I know). My accumulator totals 11 if I don't comment it out, but using the ColorIndex property, I count only five unique identifiers in all columns.

I am new to programming, so other guidance is appreciated. Code is below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub longitudinalCheck()
'activate the correct worksheet
Worksheets("Sheet7").Activate

'declare variables
Dim preStart, preEnd, postStart, postEnd, fourToSixStart, fourToSixEnd, sixStart, sixEnd, twelveStart, twelveEnd, accumulator As Integer
Dim preColumn, postColumn, fourToSixColumn, sixColumn, twelveColumn As Integer
Dim preLooper, postLooper, fourToSixLooper, sixLooper, twelveLooper As Integer
Dim accumulatorIncrementer As Integer
accumulatorIncrementer = 1
accumulator = 0

'user assigns values to variables based on dataset
'preStart = InputBox("Which row do the user ids for the precourse data start in?")
preStart = 3
'preEnd = InputBox("Which row does the user ids for the precourse data end in?")
preEnd = 427
'postStart = InputBox("Which row does the user ids for the postcourse data start in?")
postStart = 3
'postEnd = InputBox("Which row does the user ids for the postcourse data end in?")
postEnd = 427
'fourToSixStart = InputBox("Which row does the 4-6 data start in?")
fourToSixStart = 3
'fourToSixEnd = InputBox("Which row does the 4-6 data end in?")
fourToSixEnd = 44
'sixStart = InputBox("Which row does the 6 Month data start in?")
sixStart = 3
'sixEnd = InputBox("Which row does the 6 Month data end in?")
sixEnd = 38
'twelveStart = InputBox("Which row does the 12 Month data start in?")
twelveStart = 3
'twelveEnd = InputBox("Which row does the 12 Month data end in?")
twelveEnd = 46

'preColumn = InputBox("What column is the predata in?")
preColumn = 1
'postColumn = InputBox("What column is the postdata in?")
postColumn = 2
'fourToSixColumn = InputBox("What column is the 4-6 data in?")
fourToSixColumn = 3
'sixColumn = InputBox("What column is the 6 month data in?")
sixColumn = 4
'twelveColumn = InputBox("What column is the 12 month data in?")
twelveColumn = 5

'for loop runs to see how many folks went all the way through
For preLooper = preStart To preEnd
    For postLooper = postStart To postEnd
        If Cells(preLooper, preColumn) = Cells(postLooper, postColumn) Then
            For fourToSixLooper = fourToSixStart To fourToSixEnd
                If Cells(preLooper, preColumn) = Cells(fourToSixLooper, fourToSixColumn) Then
                    For sixLooper = sixStart To sixEnd
                        If Cells(preLooper, preColumn) = Cells(sixLooper, sixColumn) Then
                            For twelveLooper = twelveStart To twelveEnd
                                If Cells(preLooper, preColumn) = Cells(twelveLooper, twelveColumn) Then
                                    'accumulator = accumulator + accumulatorIncrementer
                                    Cells(preLooper, preColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                                    Cells(postLooper, postColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                                    Cells(fourToSixLooper, fourToSixColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                                    Cells(sixLooper, sixColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                                    Cells(twelveLooper, twelveColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                                ElseIf Cells(preLooper, preColumn) <> Cells(twelveLooper, twelveColumn) Then
                                End If
                            Next twelveLooper
                        ElseIf Cells(preLooper, preColumn) <> Cells(sixLooper, sixColumn) Then
                        End If
                    Next sixLooper
                ElseIf Cells(preLooper, preColumn) <> Cells(fourToSixLooper, fourToSixColumn) Then
                End If
            Next fourToSixLooper
        ElseIf Cells(preLooper, preColumn) <> Cells(postLooper, postColumn) Then
        End If
    Next postLooper
Next preLooper

'results displayed to me
MsgBox "The data has " & accumulator & " respondents that have taken all surveys."

End Sub
```

Comment: At first glance : doing `Dim aaa, bbb, ccc As Integer ` will make aaa as Variant, bbb as Variant and ccc as Integer . You may want to change that declaration part to fix the error 104

Comment: That's a lot of `InputBoxes` and nested loops. As you haven't provided a snapshot of your sheet, it's very hard to suggest a proper solution for it (I would suggest that you provide a snapshot of your sheet). If you need to ask that many questions, I would just ask the user to fill in the values in a separate sheet and then have a button on that sheet to run VBA. Also, there are much better options to find and accumulate your data in VBA rather than multiple nested loops (i.e. VLookUp, .Find depending on your requirement)

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I believe the variable declaration issue will fix the runtime 1004 error. And, yes, I am sure that the multiple nested loops are not the most logical way to go, and I intend to improve my methods for solving this problem as I learn more about programming!